# Real time update of interval timer with the use of a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make it so i can change the value of the interval timer in real time with the use of a slider. I managed to make it so i can show the current value of the slider. Can i use the same variable as the one that i am using in textbox or do i have to create a new one? Pretty sure that the solution is very simple. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

jsfiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/8bdycskp/32/
```

```js
var quotes = [
  "X",
  "Y",
  "Z"
];

// initialise current quote index
var quoteIndex = 0;
// get interval time
var interval = document.getElementById("interval").value;

// set target element
var $target = $('.container').find('h1');

// create timer function
var quoteTimer = function() {
  // set target text to current quote
  $target.fadeIn().text(quotes[quoteIndex]);
  // increment the current index, or reset to 0 if on the last quote
  quoteIndex = quoteIndex < quotes.length - 1 ? quoteIndex + 1 : 0;
}

// fire it up..!
$(document).ready(function() {
  let intervalval = setInterval(quoteTimer, interval);
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
     let v = parseInt($("#interval").val());
     clearTimeout(intervalval);
     intervalval = setInterval(quoteTimer, v);
  })
});


    
var p = document.getElementById("interval2"),
    res = document.getElementById("result");

p.addEventListener("input", function() {
    res.innerHTML = p.value + "ms";
}, false);
```

```html
<body>
  <center></br>
  <input type="text" name="interval" id="interval" value="" style="height:50px; width:500px; font-size: 25px" placeholder="Czas w ms" /></br></br>
  1ms<input name="interval2" id="interval2" type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="" /> 1000ms</br>
  <p id="result"></p>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Rozpocznij" style="padding: 10px 50px; font-size: 25px"/>  </center>
  <div class="container">
  <h1></h1>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. You just have to remove your input text and your button and add a range input. Then you bind the "onchange" event to a listener and execute the same function you have in your "click" event

Here it is a jsfiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/8bdycskp/56/

```js
// define quotes array
var quotes = [
  "AAAA",
  "BBBB",
  "CCCC"
];

// initialise current quote index
var quoteIndex = 0;
// get interval time
var interval = document.getElementById("range").value;

// set target element
var $target = $('.container').find('h1');

// create timer function
var quoteTimer = function() {
  // set target text to current quote
  $target.fadeIn().text(quotes[quoteIndex]);
  // increment the current index, or reset to 0 if on the last quote
  quoteIndex = quoteIndex < quotes.length - 1 ? quoteIndex + 1 : 0;
}

// fire it up..!
$(document).ready(function() {
  let intervalval = setInterval(quoteTimer, interval);
  $("#range").on("change", function() {
    let v = parseInt($("#range").val());
    clearTimeout(intervalval);
    intervalval = setInterval(quoteTimer, v);
  })
});
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="range" name="range" id="range" value="1000" min="100" max="5000" step="10"/>
    <div class="container">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an event listener to detect changes and then update your interval

```
var intervalval = '';

function slider() {
    clearTimeout(intervalval);
    var v = parseInt($("#interval").val());
    intervalval = setInterval(quoteTimer, v);
}
//Listen for changes
$(document).on('input', '#interval', function() {
    slider();
})
```

[See working fiddle with range slider](https://jsfiddle.net/7svqpg53/)